# Is there a more concise way to implement css' An+B micro-syntax as xpath predicates?

Tags: algorithm, xpath, css-selectors, logic, predicate

I'm creating a CSS selectors to xpath 1 converter and one detail I struggled the most with is finding a concise substitute for the [`An+B` micro-syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#anb).

Since I'm implementing it for xpath 1 and in such a way as to be as generic as possible, there are a few constraints that my generated predicates have to adhere to:

1. I (believe I) can't use `position()`, since that is dependent on possibly preceding predicates.
2. All `*-of-type` pseudo-class equivalents will be generated by external functions in the host language, because I believe there's no way to build predicates based on the name of the previous context-node in xpath 1.

   For instance, hard-coding `li:first-of-type` as

   ```
   //li[count(preceding-sibling::li) = 0]
   ```

   is fine. But dynamically coding `*:first-of-type` as something like

   ```xml
   //*[count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(.)]) = 0]
   <!-- this is probably silly anyway -->
   ```

   is not possible in xpath 1, I believe.

So, here's a "template" predicate I came up with for `nth-of-type(An+B)`, that the host language will fill with missing values:

```xml
<!-- 
  $A  represents the step (A) I will insert
  $Am represents "mod $A" I will insert if $A != 0
  $B  represents the offset (B) I will insert
  $E  represents the element name I will insert
  $O  represents the operator I will insert: <= if $A is negative, else >=
-->
[count(preceding-sibling::$E) + 1 - $B $O 0 and
 (count(preceding-sibling::$E) + 1 - $B) $Am = 0]
```

`li:nth-of-type(2n+3)` would thus become:

```xml
<!-- 
  $A  (step) = 2
  $Am (mod step) = mod $A = mod 2
  $B  (offset) = 3
  $E  (element name) = li
  $O  (comparison operator) = >=
-->
[count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3 >= 0 and
 (count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3) mod 2 = 0]
```

`li:nth-of-type(-2n+3)` would thus become:

```xml
<!-- 
  $A  (step) = -2
  $Am (mod step) = mod $A = mod -2
  $B  (offset) = 3
  $E  (element name) = li
  $O  (comparison operator) = <=
-->
[count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3 <= 0 and
 (count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3) mod -2 = 0]
```

`li:nth-of-type(3)` would thus become:

```xml
<!-- 
  $A  (step) = 0
  $Am (mod step) = absent
  $B  (offset) = 3
  $E  (element name) = li
  $O  (comparison operator) = >=

  first line seems redundant now
-->
[count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3 >= 0 and
 (count(preceding-sibling::li) + 1 - 3) = 0]
```

...etc.

As you can see, it's all a bit unwieldy. I'd preferably create a nice compact one-liner predicate, without the seemingly redundant bits and with the least need for variable substitutions (in particular the comparison operator and the step-dependent mod calculation).

Is there a more concise way to incorporate the `An+B` (step and offset) functionality that I've shown above?

Comment: "xpath 1" Don't you just love it when implementations don't stay up to date with the latest XPath standards...

Comment: Sorry, but `//li[count(preceding-sibling::li) = 0]` is the same as `//li[1]`. More general "first of a kind" needs grouping. That can't be done by element name in XPath 1.0.- 
About the `An+B`, you can rely on `position()` if you are explicit with the element: `li:nth-of-type(2n+3)` would thus become `//li[(position() - 3) mod 2 = 0]`

Comment: I don't see why you think this is impossible? 

`//*[count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(.)]) = 0]`

I tried it and it worked for me!

But strictly you should use a combination of `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` to compare element types, since different namespaces may be in scope and different prefixes associated with the same namespace URI.

e.g. here "ns1:element" and "ns2:element" are not equal strings, but the element types are the same: `<eg>
   <ns1:element xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns"/>
   <ns2:element xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns"/>
</eg>`